# Sort Dictionary by values using keys of another dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries:

```
1. Dictionary<String, Person>
2. Dictionary<Person, int>
```

I would like to sort the first dictionary by values (i.e. Person(s)) ordering it exactly the same as the order of the keys (i.e. Person(s)) in the 2nd Dictionary. What would be the simplest way?

Comment: `Dictionary` s aren't ordered, so what do you mean the order of the keys in the second `Dictionary`? Do you mean you have an `IComparer<Person>`? And what do you mean by sort a dictionary, anyway?

Comment: Eat more chicken. Accept more answers.

Comment: @Shahid - Are you sure you mean the keys of the dictionary and not the values (the `int`) of the second dictionary?

Comment: Ok sorry for not explaining it properly. I can see there is an OrderBy(keySelector). I would like to use something similar to do an OrderBy 'Values' on the first Dictionary and use the order of the list of 'Keys' in the 2nd Dictionary.

Comment: By the way in this case the keys in the 2nd dictionary are exactly the same (size and values) except in different order

Comment: @Shahid: The keys in a dictionary don't have an ordering.

Comment: @Jason: I see what you mean but I am getting confused by the LINQ's OrderBy (sorts the elements of a sequence according to a key) then. What does it actually do ?

Comment: First, OrderBy() (and other LINQ methods) don't change the original collection. OrderBy() takes a IEnumerable<T> and gives you back an IEnumerable<T> that is ordered. When you iterate over the new collection, the items will be returned in the specified order. The dictionary itself is not ordered.

Comment: @Shahid: It orders a sequence of instances of some type by a projection of that type. It will return a sequence that when iterated over is an ordering of the input sequence. For example. Let's say you have a sequence of `Person`, and you have a projection `Func<Person, string>` defined by `p => p.FirstName`. Then you can order a sequence of `Person` by saying `sequence.OrderBy(p => p.FirstName)`. This works because `string` has a default `IComparer<string>`. You can't use a projection `Func<Person, Person>` defined by `p => p` unless `Person` implements `IComparable<Person>` or `IComparable`.

Comment: @Jason & Bryan: thanks for explaining .. Conclusion is, there is a flaw in my question in the first place

Comment: @Shahid, is the second dictionary (Dictionary<Person, int>) ordered? If not, then you need to manually set the ordering yourself. If it is, then simply copy over the Dictionary.OrderBy() logic over to the first dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var ordered = dictionary1.OrderBy(p => dictionary2[p.Value]).ToArray();
```

Comment: That's ordering by the values of the second dictionary, not the keys. Frankly, there is not enough information in the question.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. You are right. It seemed so obvious to me that he wanted to order by the values because, as you said, there is no order of `Person` in the second dictionary. Thanks for noticing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, int> first = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Dictionary<int, string> second = new Dictionary<int, string>();
first.Add("a", 1);
first.Add("c", 3);
first.Add("b", 2);
first.Add("g", 7);
first.Add("d", 4);

second.Add(3, "c");
second.Add(1, "a");
second.Add(7, "g");
second.Add(2, "b");
second.Add(4, "d");

Dictionary<string, int> final = new Dictionary<string, int>();
second.ToList().ForEach(s =>
{
    if (first.ContainsValue(s.Key))
        final.Add(s.Value, s.Key);
});

foreach (var item in final)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " " + item.Value);
}
```